# AJAX with jQuery in WordPress: AJAX call not passing property value to PHP function

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

So I'm trying to build something that should be incredibly simple -- A form that has State and Area, and when you select a state, it populates the list of areas. My form has two menus, #select-region (state), and #select-area. Here's my jQuery code that is included in a .js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#select-region").change(function(){
    //alert(jQuery("#select-region").val());
    regionID = jQuery("#select-region").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://dev.sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                action: 'get_area_menu',
                region_id: regionID,
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                jQuery("#select-area").html('');
                jQuery("#select-area").append(data);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
     });
});
```

The 'get_area_menu()' function is in my functions.php file. Here's the code:

```
function get_area_menu($region_id){
    $areas = get_areas($region_id);

    $menu_output = "<option>" . count($areas) . "</option>";
    foreach($areas as $area) {
        $menu_output = $menu_output . "<option value=" . $area['area_id'] . ">" . $area['name'] . "</option>";
    }
    die($menu_output);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_area_menu', 'get_area_menu');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_area_menu', 'get_area_menu');
```

`

Now, I've verified that the 'get_areas()' function that is called in the above function is working properly when a region_id is passed to it, but for some reason the region_id variable is not being passed into  get_area_menu() from the AJAX call. FWIW, I have enqueued the script and localized it (although I still have no idea what that actually means) with this code near the top of functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('sitename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/sitename.js');
wp_localize_script( 'sitename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/sitename.js', $params);
```

Guys, I'm at my wit's end. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wordpress, so maybe this doesn't apply. But have you tried passing in `$_POST['region_id']` rather than `$region_id`? That's the standard way of accessing POST variables in PHP.

Comment: Since I'm using jQuery to get the current value of #select-region when it is changed (regionID = jQuery("#select-region").val();), that variable is not actually posted and therefore not in the "POST" scope. Maybe I'm wrong? There's nowhere actually use $_POST['region_id'] because $region_id, in this case, is used as a property within a function.

Comment: I don't understand. In your `$.ajax` call, you have this: `data: {               action: 'get_area_menu', region_id: regionID}`. That means `$_POST['action']` and `$_POST['region_id']` should exist on the PHP side. Otherwise, where else are you expecting to get the value of the region_id from?

Comment: The AJAX call is being executed on a drop-down menu change, not a form post, so how with that data exist in the post scope on the server?  The value of that drop-down is grabbed in the JS file with this code: 'regionID = jQuery("#select-region").val();'

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding how the 'data' thing works. I thought 'action' was the function you're trying call on the server and all the subsequent properties/variables are just passed in to that function. In other words, 'data: { action: 'get_area_menu', region_id: regionID}' should pass the value of "regionID" (set in JS) as a property named "region_id" into the PHP function get_area_menu(), no?

Comment: It seems you need to read up more on AJAX. It doesn't matter if a form is being submitted or not. You are sending data to the server in either case. In fact, you could think of the drop down change as triggering the submission of a mini-form. Regardless, you are sending the data to the server via `POST` (as specified in `type: 'POST'`). Therefore, the data provided will be available in the `$_POST` array on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see is in your `get_area_menu` function change this line

```
$areas = get_areas(isset($_POST['region_id']) ? $_POST['region_id'] : $region_id);
```

Comment: I am totally lost. How would the region_id get into the post scope if the form isn't being posted? Especially since the PHP code is using $region_id as a property that's passed in.

Comment: You call this function from Ajax using POST to pass parameters :)